File Manager - Telerik UI Component for Blazor - .net 8.0 - Modify Context menu

How can I remove/disable Delete, Rename on Context menu only for Folders (Delete, Rename are showed for file as current)?

How can I add more option to the context menu?


I want to customize the Context menu of Telerik Filemanager component.

For the time being, If removing the "Delete" and "Rename" options from the context menu of all types of files is an option, you can use the following CSS approach:
<style>
/*Remove "Delete" context menu option*/
.custom-context-menu .k-menu-group, .k-menu li:nth-of-type(3) {
    display: none;
}
/*Remove "Rename" context menu option*/
.custom-context-menu .k-menu-group, .k-menu li:nth-of-type(1) {
    display: none;
}

</style>

<TelerikFileManager Data="@FileManagerData"
                @bind-Path="@DirectoryPath"
                Height="400px"
                OnCreate="@OnCreateHandler"
                OnUpdate="@OnUpdateHandler"
                OnModelInit="@OnModelInitHandler"
                OnDownload="@OnDownloadHandler"
                OnDelete="@OnDeleteHandler"
                Class="custom-context-menu">
</TelerikFileManager>

